# Web-Scraping JS-driven sites without rendering

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've been recently scraping some JS-driven pages. As far as I know there are two ways of loading the content: static (ready to use HTML pages) and dynamically (making HTML code in-place from a raw data). I know about XHR, and I've been successfully intercepting some.

But now I've faced strange thing - site dynamically loads the content after the page fully loads but there are no XHRs. How can that be?

My guess is: the inner js files are making some hidden requests (which transfer the data) and building page based on responses.
What should I do?

P.S. I'm not interested in selenium-based solutions - they are well-known, but slow and inefficient. 
P.P.S. I'm a back-end developer mostly, so I'm not familiar with JS.

Comment: You can try [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) or [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)

Comment: PhantomJS isn't an option - still too slow, but pretender.io seems nice - I'll check it thanks!

Comment: Can you share a link to that site? And what info do you want to extract?

Comment: Albertoshop.de
 Brax.com
 Digel-shop.com - like these

Comment: I need to scrape goods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays you do not need to use selenium for scrapping any more. The Chrome browser can now be used in headless mode and you can than run scraping script after the page is fully loaded.
there is simple guide:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

There is nodejs library for driving it (chrome-remote-interface) but the downside is that I could not found python one.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't suit. Chrome is slow because of loading site's images and so on. I wouldn't like to use browser emulation because of that. But I guess your answer will be useful for many people!

Comment: If images are the isue just add the --disable-images flag

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to get the data using the actual api calls. So I want to find out how to get them.